# "Provide's meaning in this sentence"

Tags: sentence-meaning

The new law gives authorities a responsibility to provide aids to the disabled.

I searched the meaning of "provide" in Longman dictionary. It says "to give someone what they need, or to make sure they get it" and "provide something for/to somebody"

I don't really understand what the sentence want to express. Does it mean "Authorities have to provide/give aids to the disabled ? "

It looks so strange.

Comment: *Aids* is being used as a noun—and a countable one at that. So, it means that the law says the authorities have to give (or make available) canes to the blind, wheelchairs to those who can't walk, and so on. (Although, personally, I would have used the singular, uncountable noun—just *aid*.)

Comment: Does the sentence really mean "To give Aids, HIV, to the disabled" ? To have the disabled contracted AIDS ?

Comment: That's not what I said at all. If that's what it meant, it would be in capitals: AIDS. But it would make no sense whatsoever, as no government would ever mandate that. Look at the dictionary definition of [*aid*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aid#h2): "*something by which assistance is given : an assisting device.*"

Comment: Are you certain of the original quote? I agree with @JasonBassford's comment that the singular *aid* would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is simply:

> Authorities have to help disabled people.

In reference to your comments, this has nothing to do with acquired immune deficiency syndrome. First of all, that syndrome should always be written as an acronym (AIDS), but more importantly, why would such a despicable law exist?

Answer (score 0):

According to the sentence, the reforms in law system have mandated the authorities to assist the disabled.

The reason behind usage of such words in the sentence could be to make the affected parties, i.e. **the authorities** in this case to feel less overwhelmed due to increase their workload or incorporate a polite professional tone.

The other tone to this sentence could be , ***The reforms in law system enforce the authorities to provide aids to the disabled*** OR ***The reforms in law system enforce the authorities to provide requisite support to the disabled*** , which is clearer and blunt.

Comment: Thanks for your explain but I don't understand "to assist the disabled by giving them AIDS ?" I'm sorry I don't exactly get it.

Comment: I don't believe there needs to be a definite article. The sentence refers to all authorities generally, not any specific authorities.

Comment: @Kiw It means to provide assistance in form of basic supplies to the disabled. Which could be temporary shelter, food, clothing etc. Aids means assistance in form of supplies here. [answer edited]

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I thought AIDS only meant a disease until you explained it. Thanks